# 400 Bad Request on IIS Server on Post

Tags: windows, iis

400 Bad Request on IIS Server on Post request.

I have deployed IIS server on EC2 and have a service there, and I am posting request on EC2 service through restTemplate from my service.

After sometime I am start getting 400 Bad Request, while I am able to make call through postman.

What could be the possible problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of reasons this could be happening.   The first thing I'd do to troubleshoot is to identify if there is a substatus code for the failing request.   To do that, you'd need the IIS logs from the server (located by default in c:\inetpub\logs\Logfiles) and locate the 400 response.  The next field will be the substatus code which you can lookup at the following link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Answer (score 0):

one case could be in `settings.py` you have not added your domain name\host
add it

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "192.122.22.2",
    "jamil.com",
]
```